# "error: bind message supplies 1 parameters, but prepared statement "" requires 0" not sure the meaning behind this or how to fix it

Tags: javascript, node.js, database

I'm taking a class on databases and receiving that error when I try to run the program.

```
const express = require("express");
  const app = express();
  const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

  app.set("port", 8080);

  app.use(bodyParser.json({ type: "application/json" }));
  app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

 const Pool = require("pg").Pool;
 const config = {
          host: "localhost",
          user: "me",
          password: "64594640",
          database: "new"
 };

 const pool = new Pool(config);

 //say hello
 app.get("/hello", (req,res) => {
     res.json("Hello world!");
 });

 app.get("/workshop", async (req,res) => {
         try {
                  // find workshops
                  const template = "SELECT workshop FROM people";
                  const responce = await pool.query(template, [req.query.q]);
                  console.log(response);
          } catch (err) {
                  console.log("whoops " + err);
          }

 });

 app.listen(app.get("port"), () => {
          console.log(`Find the server at: http://localhost:${app.get("port")}/`);
 });
```

I'm running the program on node and have a postgresql database new with the owner me.

Comment: It looks like your `template` SQL does not use any parameters, but in the next line you're trying to pass some parameter to it. Maybe that's what the error is about?

Answer (score 0):

You have supplied `query` method with one parameter:

`req.query.q`

So the method searches for place to put this parameter in your `SELECT workshop FROM people` query.

It can't find the placeholder `$1` to replace with your parameter `req.query.q`.
You either forgot to put some parameters in your query or don't need to pass any parameters to it.

To see more about `query` method with parameters see example: 
https://node-postgres.com/features/queries#Parameterized%20query